# Nullpointerexception in getView of custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

I'm getting a Nullpointerexception in my custom ArrayAdapter in my App. I do not know why a Nullpointer is raised here. And i can not reproduce this exception. The exception did not appear a long time and i have no code changes, so this makes it even more strange.
The code is:

```
private class MyAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Map<String, String> selectedDevices;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        BluetoothDbAdapter dbHelper = new BluetoothDbAdapter(context);
        dbHelper.open();
        selectedDevices = dbHelper.fetchAllDevicesAsMap();
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view =  super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        CheckedTextView item = (CheckedTextView) view;
        CharSequence text = item.getText();
        if (selectedDevices.values().contains(text)) {
            item.setChecked(true);
        }
        return item;
    }

}
```

The Exception is raised in getView method in the first line. I have debugged my App and called super.getView with null parameters but no Nullpointerexception was raised, so it seemes that super have been null, but how can this be??? The StackTrace is:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
>   at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
>   at **de.hartig.abt.activity.BluetoothDeviceList$MyAdapter.getView(BluetoothDeviceList.java**:140)
>   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1408)
>   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
>   at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
>   at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:709)
>   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1580)
>   at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1240)
>   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7057)
>   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
>   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7057)
>   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
>   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
>   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
>   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7057)
>   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
>   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7057)
>   at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
>   at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4680)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Does any body know how i can solve this problem? Thanks for help!!!

Comment: I'm sorry, of course 'super' is not null too, because the Nullpointerexception is reised in ArrayAdapter createViewFromResource. So the question is how can i handle this exception? What can i return in case of this exception?

Comment: Just a suggestion - try checking logcat to see what the garbage collectior is doing and how much free memory you have. I had the same issue are having (or very similar) and it turned out to be an unhandled memory leak. Once I'd tackled the leak, the problem was fixed.

Comment: Unfortunatly i am not able to reproduce this NPE.

Answer (score 14):

You are probably calling `add` with a `null` value and the `ArrayAdapter` is choking on it. To diagnose the problem further we'd need to see the code for `fetchAllDevicesAsMap` or wherever you are adding elements to the `ArrayAdapter`.

An excerpt from [ArrayAdapter.java](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java;hb=refs/heads/master) inside `createViewFromResource`:

```
T item = getItem(position);
if (item instanceof CharSequence) {
    text.setText((CharSequence)item);
} else {
    text.setText(item.toString());
}
```

This indicates that `ArrayAdapter` will succumb to a `NullPointerException` if one of the elements in the underlying array is `null`.

Comment: The NPE could be on the `text` variable if `text = (TextView) view.findViewById(mFieldId);` results in null

Comment: I doubt this is the problem, as there would most likely be a compile error (R.id.mispelled_resource will be unresolved)

Answer (score 2):

From the stack trace you can clearly see that `super` was not null, as it did go into `android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView()`.

You can look at the source for `android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource` line 355 to try to determine the true cause of your null pointer.

**UPDATE**

I took a peek at the code and it is failing on this line `text.setText(item.toString());` so either `text` or `item` are null.

You can look at the code yourself here:
[android.widget.ArrayAdapter source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java)